# Protractor- switch from non- angular to angular

Tags: protractor, angular, e2e

Login page is non- angular. So I set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`
Then after passing the login screen, I have set  `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false`. Also, I have used `browser.refresh()`. While execution, I see all the steps executed, but shows **error message as timeout after 11 seconds**.

Comment: I've never actually been able to get this to work properly. The new way of doing this is to use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled()` and pass in true of false accordingly. I just set mine to false in the `.onPrepare()`. I'm always running into the Angular couldn't be found on this page error. Especially when using webpack, so I just disable it entirely and figure out other ways of waiting for elements to be interactable. It's been too much of a hassle with unreliable results for me to keep switching back and forth. Any of the ExpectedConditions options will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true` entirely for angular/non-angular pages and use your own wait mechanism using `ExpectedConditions` to handle elements.

Either way is using driver methods directly as below, so it won't wait for $http and $timeout

```
expect(browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.msgtext')).getText().toBe('expexted text')
```

Please let me know if you need more help and upvote this answer if you find it helpful

Comment: Thank you both. I am already handling the same way you suggested. But would like to how to get this working

Comment: Also noticed, after login-in the landing page, I see iframe tag inside the body. Should I switch to iframe and check for angular enabled

Comment: Yes, add browser.ignoreSynchronization=true just after switching to frame

Comment: My application is build using angular. But ng app is not set in body tag. Also I am not able to find any ng-model/ng-bind tags. All I could see is only _ ngcontent tags. In this case, is there any possibility to change to browser.rootE1 value and remove expected conditions. Will this work